# capybara has_content? not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, assertions

I am using capybara with ruby on rails to do some testing, and I want to see if an object in the database has content. I am using the following gems:

```
group :test do
 gem 'database_cleaner'
 gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'
end
```

I can see the object being created in the console when i run rake, but the test still fails on the has_content? assertion.

```
link = Link.last
p link #i can see the object exists here with the title and url present
assert has_content?(link.title) #fails
assert has_content?(link.url) #fails
```

Any help would be appreciated, i can get all my other assertions to pass with the exception of these two.

Comment: nevermind, i believe i misunderstood the use of has_content? Its looking through the html - duh. Sorry if i wasted anyones time :)

Comment: FWIW: Rails has a nice `.present?` method which checks values to be neither `nil` nor empty. `assert link.title.present?`